# How to Generate Sub String values From Value inserted in multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql, substring

i have 2 tables in my  database.1st is material_details and 2nd is category
in material_details i have 6 columns (Make,Series,capacitance,tolerance,material outing)
in 2nd i have(category id,category_Name)
i want to take values from users in text boxes and from that values want to generate a sub string.how can i do this? code in c sharp

this will make u understand better.......
"i am working on a demo website.on my webpage i have 5 labels and 5 text boxes. 1.category 2.make 3.series 4.capacity and the last text box is Sub string.Now i want that when ever the user fill the 1 to 4 text boxes.a sub string should be generated by the values of these text boxes..for example..if user enter the category as "school" make as "samsung" series as "1234" the sub string that will be generates is like "SCH-SAM-123"..the first three words from all field.""

Comment: What does a database have to do with text boxes and sub string? What are you asking? What are you having problems with? Please expand your question.

Comment: @siva actually i have a web form .i want user to insert the basic details in the fields of the web form,as the user done with the details and clicks submit button 1 sub string should be created from user values.

Comment: That really doesn't explain anything. Can you show some code along with and explanation of what it's doing and what you want it to do?

Comment: siva..i had eloborated my ques..plz go through it

Answer (score 0):

```
//these codes will help you retrieve the values of each Text box to strings
TextBox objTextBox1 = (TextBox)input1;
string theText1 = objTextBox.Text;
```

Similarly generate 4 strings for each text box. 
theText1
theText2
theText3
theText4

```
//This will extract first three characters from a string
string sub1 = theText1.Substring(0, 3);
```

Similarly extract characters from all the strings created above.

If you want the characters to be in upper case use "string.ToUpper()" method

Once all the strings are extracted, concatenate all strings

```
string results = sub1 + "-" + sub2 +  "-" + sub3  "-" + sub4;

//Check the result
Console.WriteLine(results);
```

I hope this guide will help you to get your intended results.

Thanks

Comment: That wasnt an exact code for you question. That was a sample structure. If you could show what you have worked on already. I could refine my answer to better suite your problem.

Comment: i am working on a demo website.on my webpage i have 5labels and 5text boxs. 1.category 2.make 3.series 4.capacity and the last textbox is Substring.Now i want that when ever the user fill the 1 to 4 textboxes.a sub string should be generated by the values of these text boxes..for example..if user enter the category as "school" make as "samsung" series as "1234" the sub string that will be generates is like "SCH-SAM-123"..the first three words from all field..hope u got my ques

Comment: @AnimeshMishra - check for the refined answer.

Comment: y it is giveing me an error on input  (Text Box)input1;...the msg that is been displayed is                         'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox1' does not contain a definition for 'input1'

Comment: @AnimeshMishra "input1" was an example name i used here. You have to replace it with the name you have used in your project. Kindly read basics on how to retrieve values from Text Box.